# How can I calculate $d$ in this sum with a min-term that depends on $d$?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, python

Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $e_i \in \mathbb{N_{0}}$, $l_i \in \mathbb{N}$, $b_i \in \{0,1,2\}$ where $1 \le i \le n, i \in \mathbb{N}$.

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n{\min\left(e_i + \frac{b_i \cdot d}{4}, l_i\right)} = n \cdot d
$$

How can I determine $d$ (in a program, with two decimals precision)?

The maximum of the left-hand sum is $L = \sum_{i=0}^n{l_i}$. So a brute-force approach would be to simply increment $d$ from $0$ up to $\frac{L}{n}$ (with $L = \sum_{i=0}^n{l_i}$) in steps of my desired (finite) precision and measure the error of the two sides of the equation, then use the best result.

A better approach would be to use some optimization library; but I am not sure what kind of optimization problem this is and what libraries and algorithms are suited here.

But preferably: Is there an analytical solution? Or at least, a more elegant approach?

Comment: A better brute force approach would be to use a search algorithm instead of testing all increments of $d$. You start with the interval $[a_0, b_0]$ where $a_0 = 0, b_0 = \frac Ln$. Set $d_0 = \frac12(a_0 + b_0)$. if $d_0$ is too high, set $a_1 = a_0, b_1 = d_0$. If $d_0$ is too low, set $a_1 = d_0, b_1 = b_0$. Rinse and repeat until $b_n-a_n$ is less than twice your tolerance. If this is not fast enough for you, there are much more sophisticated root finding algorithms to use instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtract $L$ from both sides, and you get
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\min\left(e_i-l_i + \frac{b_i \cdot d}{4}, 0\right) = n \cdot d - L$$
Now break the indices $1, \dots, n$ up into two sets

- $A = \left\{i\ \middle |\ b_i \ne 0\text{ and }d\le \frac{4(l_i - e_i)}{b_i}\right\}$
- $B = \{i\mid b_i = 0\}$
- All other indices.

Let $K = L + \sum_{i\in B}\min(e_i-l_i, 0)$. We have
$$\sum_{i\in A} \frac{b_i \cdot d}{4} = n \cdot d - K - \sum_{i\in A}(e_i-l_i)$$
$$d = \dfrac{K + \sum_{i\in A}(e_i-l_i)}{n - \sum_{i\in A}\frac{b_i}4}$$

This suggests the strategy:

1. Since $B$ and $K$ do not depend on $d$, calculate $K$ as above, and throw out all indices with $b_i = 0$.
2. For the remaining indices $i$, calculate $r_i = \dfrac{4(l_i - e_i)}{b_i}$, and sort them in decreasing order.
3. Set $d = \frac Kn$ (assumes $A$ is empty) and compare to the largest $r_i$.

   - if $d > r_i$, then end. This $i\notin A$ and this value of $d$ is correct.
   - if $d \le r_i$, add $e_i - l_i$ to $K$ and subtract $\frac{b_i}4$ from $n$ (the current $i$ was in $A$). Repeat with the next largest $r_i$.
   - If there are no more $r_i$, quit. The equation cannot be satisfied.